# Wordpress changes "" into «»

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

I'm making a French translation on our website. In the translation we use "" for some products we make. But Wordpress changes all the "" into «».

For example "Product name" is displayed like: « Product name ». I've tried commenting the DB_Charset and CB_Collate but that didn't help.

Someone that knows a fix for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please add **meta** tag for charset in functions.php file **Or** in wp-config.php .

Paste the below code in your current active theme **functions.php** file.

```
add_action('wp_head','add_charset_metetag');
function add_charset_metetag(){?>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php } ?>
```

Paste the below code in **wp-config.php** file, located at wordpress root directory:

**Database Charset to use in creating database tables.**

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); 
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

For more help see this link : [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets)